# How to retrieve css text from style added with insertRule?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I have a  tag whose content has been added dynamically with the [insertRule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule) function.
I would like to retrieve the text content of the related style

I've tried `document.getElementById('style').innerHTML` and  `document.getElementById('style').text`, but they return **empty string**

```
// Add style a tag to head
var style = document.createElement("style");
style.id = "style",
style.type = "text/css",
document.head.appendChild(style);
var sheet = style.sheet;
// Insert some stylesheet rules
sheet.insertRule("p {background-color: red}", sheet.length);
sheet.insertRule("p {color: white}", sheet.length);
// Try to retrieve the css text
document.getElementById('style').innerHTML; // returns ""
document.getElementById('style').text; // returns undefined
```

I expect to get the text css present in the stylesheet. 
For example, the above style must return 
`p {background-color: red}
p {color: white}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var style = document.createElement("style");
    style.id = "style",
    style.type = "text/css",
    document.head.appendChild(style);
    var sheet = style.sheet;
    // Insert some stylesheet rules
    sheet.insertRule("p {background-color: red}", sheet.length);
    sheet.insertRule("p {color: white}", sheet.length);
    sheet.insertRule("div {color: green}", sheet.length);

    function getRule(){
      var cssFullText = "";
      [...sheet.cssRules].forEach(({cssText})=> cssFullText += `${cssText} `);
      console.log(cssFullText)
    }
```

```html
<p>Test line</p>
    <p>Test line</p>
    <button onClick="getRule()">Get css HTML</button>
```

Comment: I do not want to get the text for all css tags, but only for one whose css attributes have been added dynamically **insertRule**. In this case elm.innerText does not work. Return empty string ""

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Stylesheet apparently become part of the `document` object.

So `document.styleSheets` will return a list (an array) of styleSheets attached to the document.

Each style sheet then can be accessed by looping through it.

`document.styleSheets[0].cssRules` will give you the array of cssRules of the style sheet.

Again, you can loop through `cssRules` to access rules written there.

**Note:**

Firefox throws `SecurityError: The operation is insecure.` error if you try to access `cssRules`.

[Read more about CSSStyleSheet interface.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. I have added sample snippet to get all style tags.

```js
function addStyle(styles) { 
              
  /* Create style document */ 
  var css = document.createElement('style'); 
  css.type = 'text/css'; 

  if (css.styleSheet)  
  css.styleSheet.cssText = styles; 
  else  
  css.appendChild(document.createTextNode(styles)); 

  /* Append style to the tag name */ 
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(css); 
  
  // Try to retrieve the css text
  var styleTag = document.getElementsByTagName('style');
  for(var i=0; i<styleTag.length;i++){
    console.log(styleTag[i].innerHTML); // returns
  }
} 

/* Set the style */ 
var styles = 'h1 { color: green }'; 
styles += ' body { text-align: center }'; 

/* Function call */ 
window.onload = function() { addStyle(styles) };
```

Comment: @syed-mohamed-aladeenthanks for your answer I'am trying to get css text for a style tag whose css attributes have been added dynamically **insertRule**. In this case elm. innerHTML does not work. You ca try the code in my main question post